# Elemento Table com varias linhas mas diferentes nº de celulas, como centrar?(HTML)

Tags: html, css, table

Boas, eu tenho uma  duvida, numa tabela tenho 2 tr um com 4 td's e outra com 3
Seria possível transformar isto:
[image: tabela com diferentes células mas não centradas na tabela.]

numa tabela assim:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
mas sem ser preciso criar 2 tabelas

ou seja, ter diferentes numeros de celulas em 2 linhas, mas centrar as celulas.

eis o codigo da primeira imagem:

```
<table class="bordaredonda">
    <tr>
        <td><img class="ex1" src="icon/Neutros/CaveSpiderFAce.png" ALT="Aranha das Cavernas"></td>
        <td><img class="ex1" src="icon/Neutros/Endermanface.png" ALT="Enderman"></td>
        <td><img class="ex1" src="icon/Neutros/PolarBearFace.png" ALT="Urso Polar"></td>
        <td><img class="ex1" src="icon/Neutros/Snowgolemhead.png" ALT="Golem de Neve"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img class="ex1" src="icon/Neutros/Spiderface.png" ALT="Aranha"></td>
        <td><img class="ex1" src="icon/Neutros/Vg_face.png" ALT="Golem de Ferro"></td>
        <td><img class="ex1" src="icon/Neutros/Zombiepigmanface.png" ALT="Zombie Pigman"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Obrigado pela atenção

Comment: Tem que ser usando `<table>`? Ou pode ser usando uma estrutura diferente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olha, com tabela eu realmente não posso te ajudar, mas vê se assim te serve.

```css
img {
 width: 50px;
}
.row {
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
}
.row div {
 display: inline-block;
 min-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
 <div><img src="http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/orange/stackoverflow-4-xxl.png" ALT="Aranha das Cavernas"></div>
    <div><img src="http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/orange/stackoverflow-4-xxl.png" ALT="Enderman"></div>
    <div><img src="http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/orange/stackoverflow-4-xxl.png" ALT="Urso Polar"></div>
    <div><img src="http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/orange/stackoverflow-4-xxl.png" ALT="Golem de Neve"></div>
 <div><img src="http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/orange/stackoverflow-4-xxl.png" ALT="Golem de Neve"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
 <div><img src="http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/orange/stackoverflow-4-xxl.png" ALT="Aranha das Cavernas"></div>
    <div><img src="http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/orange/stackoverflow-4-xxl.png" ALT="Enderman"></div>
    <div><img src="http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/orange/stackoverflow-4-xxl.png" ALT="Urso Polar"></div>
    <div><img src="http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/orange/stackoverflow-4-xxl.png" ALT="Golem de Neve"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**INLINE-BLOCK**

Aproveitando-se da propriedade *inline-block* acredito que você vai alcançar o resultado desejado (note que essa solução não se aplica a tabelas):

```css
.linha {
   height:106px;
   text-align: left;
}

.coluna {
   display: inline-block;
   float: left;
   border: 1px solid #444;
   background: #C34;
   width: 20%;
   height:106px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="linha">
   <div class="coluna"></div>
   <div class="coluna"></div>
   <div class="coluna"></div>
   <div class="coluna"></div>
   <div class="coluna"></div>
</div>

<div class="linha">
   <div class="coluna"></div>
   <div class="coluna"></div>
   <div class="coluna"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Vê se dessa forma se adapta visualmente ao que você quer:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>a</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Talvez com `<table>` não seja possível fazer isso.

Tente utilizar `flexbox`.

Exemplo:

```css
.caixa {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="caixa">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
  <div class="item">10</div>
</div>
```

Com o `flexbox` você tem mais dinamismo com seus itens e independente da quantidade, eles sempre vão estar alinhados.

Apenas tome cuidado, essa especificação varia de acordo com a versão de cada navegador:

- A nomenclatura atual é `display: flex;`
- Para navegadores antigos deve-se usar `display: flexbox;`
- E para os mais antigos ainda, usa-se `display: box;`

[Aqui](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) tem um guia mais completo com todas as informação sobre o `flexbox`. Dá uma conferida.